# As a junior developer, how can I improve if I work with legacy code?

Tags: work-environment, career-development, software-development, teamwork

I graduated in Compsci related course.
I was not great at coding during gradschool, but had some basic OOP knowledge, C programming, Java, Python (with django framework), SQL, and front-end with web technologies (html, css, js).

I did some sort of internship in a small startup during gradschool working with site building using WordPress/PHP/SQL, which was okay.

After graduation I spent 6 months job searching, had some gigs, and spent time studying more front-end web dev, used source control (git) to manage versioning.

I got hired last year, and today I am working with drupal 7, php 7.4 on a large company for over a year now. The tech stack is basically legacy drupal, php templates for front end mixed with some JS, and lots of third party software plugged into drupal back-end.

They hired me through a bootcamp, but on the bootcamp I had drupal 9 training.
The job is fully remote, which is nice, the pay is not bad but not awesome either, I get paid in brazilian reais, the company is brazilian, but our clients are north americans.

Regarding the team, we are 3 devs, 1 QA and 1 scrum master.
I am the only jr dev on the team, the other 2 are more senior, so they say.

One of the the devs is very grumpy and not very helpful lol, but I get on with it, the other is based on other time zone/country than the majority of the team.
He has 5 years of experience, and the other grumpy dev is 5+ years experienced as well.

I have been studying on my free time and working on personal projects, with PHP, drupal 10 and relational db's, nothing fancy though. Studied a bit of react 2, which was fun.

I feel I am always lagging behind the team (I know I am a junior dev, but that's how I feel), I really want to get better soon so I can secure my job or get a better position. I wonder if working with more new drupal CMS/CMF is better, I don't know.

I also started psychotherapy because I was restless during some nights and had lots of anxiety, which today is way better.

Any help is welcome.

Thank you all.

Comment: What question are you actually asking here? There's some things you are clearly struggling with - but no direct question.

Comment: Very little of the question body seems relevant to the question title. Perhaps it could be edited down to focus on the actual question? — Also, while most people prefer writing new systems, a large part of software development involves existing code, so being able to a) understand it, b) work with it, and c) improve it is a very important skill worth learning.

Comment: And one of the ways you learn to code is by seeing how other people have done so.

Answer (score 2):

Working with legacy code CAN be a way to improve. It can also be a way to stagnate. It all depends on how you approach the problems.

Cleaning up legacy code means fixing bugs. Bugs are both coding errors and design errors.

When dealing with coding errors, it helps to ask, "why did this type of coding error occur?" If you can identify the thinking error, factors in the way that the code was written that made the thinking error less obvious, and think of ways to improve how to structure / write code so that errors become less common, then you are using the coding errors to improve.

Design errors are the reason why certain bugs are not obvious, happen only under load, or happen rarely and seemingly at random times. You often can't replicate them. But they exist because the original designer didn't think of certain factors that the code would be facing. If you can identify the factors, you are improving your ability to design systems that will handle those factors. It often takes imagination and asking seemingly crazy questions to find the factors.

In short, asking the "why" questions as you deal with legacy code can help you improve.

Answer (score 0):

Working with legacy code is where all of us start. That's how you learn the existing code base, the customer needs and priorities, the constraints upon meeting those needs, the good ideas people have had in the past for addressing them ... and, yes, the bad ideas, so you can help design better ones. Debugging and patching is one of the best ways to learn an existing product, even if it isn't your favorite thing to do and even if it's especially painful when you don't know the codebase yet.

Only after you have a sense of the architecture will you be in a position to start extending, improving, and eventually replacing it.

You're highly educated, but don't have much real-world experience yet. This is how you get that experience. If you are willing to accept that there is a bootstrapping process, it can be fun and educational, even if it isn't what you might have expected. And the more you dig in and do this right, the faster you'll be able to graduate out of it.

(Assuming you want to. I've known a few people who actually preferred debugging and fixing to coding de novo, and were particularly good at it. I've always considered them extremely valuable team members.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort answering my question Keshlam, it is very helpful to hear from more experienced people. Thank you!